# Replace string in DomDocument

Tags: php

Sorry for the question but in this case I can't resolve my problem. 
I load a directory with XML files. I want to retrieve for each content tag the but without jump lines.

For example : if i have :

```
ARCHI LEAD > MSA > 70% (pblme !)

ARCHI FONC

EDE (spec OPE specifiques à OCC) > 10%
```

I want to have :

```
ARCHI LEAD > MSA > 70% (pblme !)
ARCHI FONC
EDE (spec OPE specifiques à OCC) > 10%
```

My code:

```
 $doc->load("./comments/comments".trim($lineContent, PHP_EOL).".xml");
 $noeudsPresentation = $doc->getElementsByTagName("content");
 $count = $noeudsPresentation->length;
 $i=0;
 $j=0;
 while($i < $count){
    $file= fopen("comments.txt", "a+");
    $tasks = $noeudsPresentation->item($i++)->nodeValue;
    $tasks3 = str_replace("\n", "", $tasks);
    echo $tasks3;
    file_put_contents("fichier2", $tasks3,FILE_APPEND);
  }
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Anything in there look like XML to anyone else??? It certainly does not look like XML to me

Comment: Oh now it makes more sence

Comment: You could try `$tasks = trim($noeudsPresentation->item($i++)->nodeValue;));`

Comment: Exactly **HOW** is this code not working?

Comment: To remove the extra line break, you may replace 2 line breaks with one, e.g.: str_replace("{$linebreak}{$linebreak}","{$linebreak}", $string)

Answer (score 0):

are you on windows ? in this case you should use "\r\n" instead of "\n"

globaly you can use rtrim() instead of str_replace()

Comment: To remove the extra line break, you may reaplce 2 line breaks with one, e.g.: `str_replace("{$linebreak}{$linebreak}","{$linebreak}", $string)`